# Non-HATEOAS examples

Tags: rest, hateoas

I have been looking into REST, specifically [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) on Wikipedia, and it is stated that

> The principle is that a client interacts with a network application entirely through hypermedia provided dynamically by application servers

How else is a client going to interact with with an app, if not through hypermedia?

What are some code examples of non-HATEOAS interactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-HATEOAS APIs require prior knowledge about the resources and relationships between them.

For example, if thinking about a library API, a 'book' resource may have a name or ID of its author as an attribute. To get more information about the author the API client has to somehow know that the 'author' resource has specific context path and that it's ID is the attribute value. The things get even more complex if client would want to borrow that specific book. To do that it has to know that a POST request has to be done to create some specific resource with certain attributes (like the book's ID). The knowledge of how to do such things has to be hardcoded in the client implementation. In HATEOAS each 'book' would have links to all related resources and it would also contain information about actions that are related to that book.

The PayPal Customer Disputes API could serve as a real world example non-HATEOAS API. Check the ['list disputes' part](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/#disputes_get-disputes): it provides a list of resources with various attributes. Then see [the 'provide evidence' part](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/#disputes_provide-evidence). It says that the client may provide a resource related to a dispute. It is not possible to figure it out just by following links in the resources in the API. If it was HATEOAS then there should be a link of some sort in the 'dispute' resource that would convey the possibility of adding an 'evidence' to each dispute. You, as a programmer, have to read the documentation in order to know that 'disputes' can have 'evidences' added.

I really recommend [this video](https://vimeo.com/20781278) as an excellent learning material about what HATEOAS is and how relationships between resources can be expressed.

Answer (score 1):

The important part you are missing is

> A REST client needs no prior knowledge about how to interact with any
>   particular application or server beyond a generic understanding of
>   hypermedia

The idea is that, without knowing what resources are available from your API, or how to interact with them, a client can use HATEOAS to discover your APIs dynamically and how to interact with them.

For example:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "/orders" },
        "next": { "href": "/orders?page=2" }
    }
}
```

From `self` I can infer I am currently at `/orders`/ and from `next` the next set resources are available at `/orders?page=2`.

More than that, it also tells me from a given resource what actions are available to me base on that resource state

i.e. in this instance, there should be a second page of orders, otherwise `next` wouldn't be an option. (it would be in the response)

Have a look at the [Hal Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser) which allows you to dynamically navigate an API without any prior knowledge of it.

Comment: A client is a programmer/person, and not a program, because a program doesn't know what those links mean/represent right?

Comment: nope, if your client (application) is aware of the hateoas spec it could easily navigate the api, here is an example http://dracoblue.github.io/hateoas-browser/ the website knows nothing about the api but is able to navigate the api